# How to reload angularjs app with hidden query params?

Tags: angularjs

I have a link to access angularjs application like this one:

```
127.0.0.1:9000/#/doc?abc=def
```

When user opens that link, he/she opens the application. After the application is loaded and query params is extracted successfully, i hide these query params by this code:

```
$location.search("");
```

Now, the link in address bar is switched to **127.0.0.1:9000/#/doc**. If the user reloads the page( by F5 or reload button of browser), I want to reload the application with hidden params before. How can i do that?

Comment: Obviously you need to store the query string somewhere, such as in a cookie, local storage, or on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the parameters you are hiding and then restore them before the reload event. Since there is no way to actually capture the reload event, you will have to rely on the event that fires before the window is unloaded (when the users leaves the page or reloads it) to reload those parameters.

`$window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // restore parameters here
};`

Comment: Wow, this solution works for my case. I even didn't think about onbeforeunload event. Thanks a lot